# Mean and Variance of SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

What is the mean and the variance of $y_t$, given the following SDE:

> $dy_t = -x_t y_t dt + \sigma_1 dW^1_t$
>
> $dx_t = -\sigma_2 y_t dW^2_t$

$W^1$ and $W^2$ are (possibly correlated) Wiener processes.

Comment: Call the correlation of the two Wiener processes $\rho$.